# read.table ignores some \t and \n in a table

Tags: r, read.table

I've encountered a strange problem when reading in an annotation file from an RNAseq experiment.

I am trying to read in the tab-separated file (http://we.tl/qCjv4N3LF2) and then search the annotations (in the fourth column) for the pattern "bahd", to find entries like "bahd acyltransferase dcr" and then display all the IDs (first column) that belong to these entries. The code is:

```
ShootAnnot<-read.table("annotation1.txt",sep="\t")
matches<-grep("bahd",ShootAnnot[,4],ignore.case=TRUE)
ShootAnnot[matches,1]
```

Weirdly, I noticed this did not find all the gene annotations that I know to be there - only 9 matches out of 12 in the file. When I scanned the table for the missing entries I found one line in the file where it seems R failed to interpret the separation patterns "\t" and "\n" for a bit.

look at line 4825 in the dataset:

```
ShootAnnot[4825,]
```

for some reason, the sixth cell in that line contains a big chunk of data, with many complete lines and the appropriate "\t" and "\n" cell and line separation patterns all in one cell. Then it suddenly jumps back into separating cells and lines correctly.
I have got a bunch of these files, so I would like to make sure I can resolve any issues like that automatically. Any ideas what might be causing this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why it goes haywire (maybe a DOS CR/LF thing), but the file is pretty big and if you plug it into `data.table` you will get a pretty decent speedup just from reading the data.

```
library(data.table)
ShootAnnot <- fread("~/Downloads/annotation1.txt")
ShootAnnot[like(Blast2GO_GO_Description,"bahd"), "#ID", with=FALSE]
```

which will give you

```
                       #ID
 1: c112902_g1_i1_m.105401
 2:    c11459_g1_i1_m.4290
 3:    c11459_g2_i1_m.4292
 4: c186946_g1_i1_m.110882
 5:    c24956_g1_i1_m.8768
 6: c265515_g1_i1_m.117383
 7:   c28096_g1_i1_m.10253
 8:   c37936_g1_i1_m.14867
 9:   c40683_g1_i1_m.17292
10:   c54651_g1_i1_m.34709
11:   c54651_g2_i1_m.34711
12:       c921_g1_i1_m.351
```

(you don't have any non-lower-case "bahd"'s in your file)

Comment: thank you, that works. Still don't know what caused the problem in the first place, but the data.table package seems to get around it.